# Best practice in declaring events in C#

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I know the following two methods work, but I wonder if one is better in terms of performance / maintenance / whatever.

The short way:

```
  public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

The long way:

```
  private EventHandler _myEvent;
  public event EventHandler MyEvent
  {
     add { _myEvent += value; }
     remove { _myEvent -= value; }
  }
```

The long way seems similar to encapsulating members with properties, which is indeed a good practice. But does this apply to event handlers?

Comment: Why is auto properties bad practice?

Comment: Maybe because I'm lazy, but I'd always go for the short version :)

Comment: My first guess is that the short way is more than enough for the majority of cases. The long way is required when you actually NEED it, ie. you need to do some extra stuff when events are registered or not.

Comment: @Lews : I dont mean auto properties, but public members. ex: `public int Number;` is bad practice. `public int Number { get; set; }` is not.

Comment: sometimes having the actual delegate is also necessary for debugging, clearing the invocation list etc.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In this case, the argument of "good practice" is a little tricker; the first is a "field-like event"; you note:

> The long way seems similar to encapsulating members with properties,

but: this is encapsulated (behind `add`/`remove`) either way; so by comparison to properties, it is really the difference between:

```
public int Foo {get;set;}
```

and

```
private int foo;
public int Foo {
    get { return foo; }
    set { foo = value; }
}
```

In which case I would say "use the first one unless you have an actual reason not to" - it is still hidden behind accessors. Additionally, it is important to note that your second example is **not** what a field-like event (the first example) expands to : the compiler adds thread-safety into the mix. So: I would say use the first sample:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

Note that the "how" for the thread-safety depends on which compiler version (and indeed, which specification) you use. In recent Microsoft C# compilers, it does this with `Interlocked` operations (`CompareExchange` etc), so it does not require a dedicated private synchronization object.

Answer (score 5):

The first way does exactly the same underneath with creating private `EventHandler` with the name `MyEvent`. When it's accessed within the class event handler is returned (i.e. no problem with calling delegate) when it's called outside of class (`myClassInstance.MyEvent += SomeHandler`/`myClassInstance.MyEvent -= SomeHandler`) `Add`/`Remove` methods are called respectively. And these methods are the same (except they add thread-safety) as those you've written in the second way.

So why do you want to write more code when you actually don't need it?

Comment: actually, they're not quite the same; the compiler includes thread-safety for the field-like event example (the first one)

Answer (score 1):

To check what Marc Gravel mean i tried the following code:

```
public event EventHandler MyEventShortWay;

private EventHandler _myEvent;
public event EventHandler MyEventLongWay
{
    add { _myEvent += value; }
    remove { _myEvent -= value; }
}
```

I was surprised by what was generated (I edited the decompiled variable name) :

```
private EventHandler _myEventShortWay;

public event EventHandler MyEventShortWay
    {
        add
        {
            EventHandler handler2;
            EventHandler myEventShortWay = this._myEventShortWay;
            do
            {
                handler2 = myEventShortWay;
                EventHandler handler3 = (EventHandler)Delegate.Combine(handler2, value);
                myEventShortWay = Interlocked.CompareExchange<EventHandler>(ref this._myEventShortWay, handler3, handler2);
            }
            while (myEventShortWay != handler2);
        }
        remove
        {
            EventHandler handler2;
            EventHandler myEventShortWay = this._myEventShortWay;
            do
            {
                handler2 = myEventShortWay;
                EventHandler handler3 = (EventHandler)Delegate.Remove(handler2, value);
                myEventShortWay = Interlocked.CompareExchange<EventHandler>(ref this._myEventShortWay, handler3, handler2);
            }
            while (myEventShortWay != handler2);
        }
    }

    private EventHandler _myEvent;

    public event EventHandler MyEventLongWay
    {
        add
        {
            this._myEvent = (EventHandler) Delegate.Combine(this._myEvent, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            this._myEvent = (EventHandler)Delegate.Remove(this._myEvent, value);
        }

    }
```